# Is there any website having command line environment of Linux, for practicing commands?

Tags: linux, shell

I was wondering whether I could practice LINUX commands and shell scripting, online, over a website which could provide me an editor to practice them. And I know that probably the easiest thing to do would be to download a Linux LIVE CD and then practice shell scripting, but apart from it, I want to practice them online, anywhere I want, anytime I want and on any system, without bothering about booting from a LIVE CD.

Comment: Take a look at [http://pcfo.ga/clinux](http://pcfo.ga/clinux), it's like a free Linux machine running on CentOS 6, you'll have your own account on that system but you won't have root permissions. You can however submit the root commands through the website and once they are approved, they will be executed. Have fun!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a quite a good one here:

Javascript PC Emulator - http://bellard.org/jslinux/

---

Related:

- [How does Linux emulator in Javascript by Fabrice Bellard work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030407/how-does-linux-emulator-in-javascript-by-fabrice-bellard-work)
- [Simulating linux terminal in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19561188/1983854)

Comment: Is it that running the whole kernel in my browser memory means it will be extremely slow and inefficient. I tried, and its slow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site [linuxzoo](http://linuxzoo.net/) that provides you the linux environment, but you need to use a emulator(like Putty) to connect to this webserver and execute the commands. please go through the site it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've played with http://cb.vu/ a bit...pretty cool

Comment: Suggesting an option with extremely restricted shell isn't a great idea.  Even the most common commands don't work on this one.

Answer (score 1):

May be www.webminal.org (I'm involved in this project :P)